# explode results then implode php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the contents of a column which has contents stored as 3,2 then I'm using the explode function to separate them. The values separated are then used to query another table to bring names. Next I want to implode the results like burger, fries. But the results are not separated by the comma but are like burgerfries... This is what I have done:

```
$sql = "SELECT items FROM orders";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$exploded = explode(",", $array['items']);

foreach ($exploded as $row){
    $query = "SELECT food_name FROM foodlist WHERE food_id = $row";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    $imploded = implode(", ", $arr);

    echo $imploded;

}
```

Comment: You're imploding a single item inside of your loop. You'd need to build and implode the list outside of your loop. And from what you describe, you could actually achieve this with a single query. If you post your tables, with sample data and I can show you.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: The `implode(', '...)` only has the single column/element to implode, so you will never see your delimiter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because every `$arr` only contains one ingredient, so you're actually `implode()`ing just one element, echoing it, and then echoing other ingredients not separated by anything, so they show together.

You can add them to an array and then implode them:

```
$sql = "SELECT items FROM orders";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$exploded = explode(",", $array['items']);

$ingredients = [];
foreach ($exploded as $row){
    $query = "SELECT food_name FROM foodlist WHERE food_id = $row";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    $ingredients[] = $arr["food_name"];
}

echo implode(", ", $ingredients);
```

---

**PRO TIP**, it's a bad idea to have your fields separated by a comma like that in the database. You should [**normalize**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) that field, have another table called `ingredients` and a pivot table called `order_ingredient` containing every ingredient a specific order has, then you can simply `JOIN` the ingredients by ID and get them all at once, instead of doing [N+1 queries](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/) which will kill your performance *fast*.

The structure would look like this:

[image]

And the query something like

```
SELECT ingredient FROM orders o JOIN order_ingredient oi ON oi.order_id = o.id JOIN ingredients i ON oi.ingredient_id = i.id
```

which will return all your ingredients with just one query.

Comment: I agree, I'm thrown off by the fact he said he was actually getting `burgerfries`. I think he missed a variable when pasting the code here. I'll edit just in case, thanks.

Comment: RIght, it seemed confusing... kind of an odd way to do things, which is why I like how you explain to make a better relationship table.

Comment: @ishegg, I'll look into that suggestion given, but what you've given me has actually worked.

Comment: @ishegg Just an update, I normalized my database with something similar to your suggestion. Thanks for your advice. Really appreciate..

Comment: I'm happy to hear! Good luck and don't hesitate to come back and ask a new question if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you have already accepted an answer.

If you want to substantially reduce the number of queries you're executing, you could use the following single query to get a comma separated list of food items for all orders.

```
SELECT o.id, GROUP_CONCAT(f.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS food
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN food f ON FIND_IN_SET(f.id, o.items) > 0
GROUP BY o.id
```

Here's an SQL fiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0004c/2

But the correct solution would be to normalize your database structure.

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer This is the smart single-query approach that I'd recommend.  Otherwise you'll be doing n+1 queries -- not great practice.  Whether you move the green tick or not is up to you, but you should be implementing this approach.

Comment: @mickmackusa this is a great answer (would've never thought of it) but how is it better than actually normalizing the data, you know, what relational databases were made for?

Comment: Yes, It should be normalized, and a single-query solution should be implemented.

Comment: @mickmackusa so you'd recommend this over the second part of my answer?

Comment: A heated debate. Love it. @ishegg, your answer is correct - you answered the original question, _and_ also outlined that the data _should_ be normalized. I was merely providing a more optimized solution for OPs existing database structure.

Comment: @fubar absolutely, like I said I think your answer is great. I was just wondering if there's a situation in which this could be better than normalizing, other than "I can't change my structure".